# Optimizing query in the MySQL slow-query log

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

Our database is set up so that we have a `credentials` table that hold multiple different types of credentials (logins and the like). There's also a `credential_pairs` table that associates some of these types together (for instance, a user may have a password and security token).

In an attempt to see if a pair match, there is the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.credential_id FROM credential_pairs AS cp
INNER JOIN credentials AS c1 ON (cp.primary_credential_id   = c1.credential_id)
INNER JOIN credentials AS c2 ON (cp.secondary_credential_id = c2.credential_id)
WHERE c1.data = AES_ENCRYPT('Some Value 1', 'encryption key')
AND   c2.data = AES_ENCRYPT('Some Value 2', 'encryption key');
```

This query works fine and gives us exactly what we need. HOWEVER, it is constantly showing in the slow query log (possibly due to lack of indexes?). When I ask MySQL to "explain" the query it gives me:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                          | key                 | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c1    | ref  | credential_id_UNIQUE,credential_id,ix_credentials_data | ix_credentials_data | 22      | const |     1 | Using where; Using temporary   |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | ref  | credential_id_UNIQUE,credential_id,ix_credentials_data | ix_credentials_data | 22      | const |     1 | Using where                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cp    | ALL  | NULL                                                   | NULL                | NULL    | NULL  | 69197 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------------+
```

I have a feeling that last entry (where it shows 69197 rows) is probably the problem, but I am FAR from a DBA... help?

---

**credentials table:**

```
CREATE TABLE  `credentials` (
  `hidden_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `credential_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data` blob NOT NULL,
  `credential_status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `insert_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `insert_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete_user` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`hidden_id`,`credential_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `credential_id_UNIQUE` (`credential_id`),
  KEY `credential_id` (`credential_id`),
  KEY `data` (`data`(10)),
  KEY `credential_status` (`credential_status`(10))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1572 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**credential_pairs Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE  `credential_pairs` (
  `hidden_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `credential_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `primary_credential_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `secondary_credential_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hidden_id`,`credential_id`),
  KEY `primary_credential_id` (`primary_credential_id`(10)),
  KEY `secondary_credential_id` (`secondary_credential_id`(10))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=500 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**credentials Indexes:**

```
+-------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type     | Comment |
+-------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| credentials |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | hidden_id     | A         |      186235 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credentials |          0 | PRIMARY              |            2 | credential_id | A         |      186235 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credentials |          0 | credential_id_UNIQUE |            1 | credential_id | A         |      186235 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credentials |          1 | credential_id        |            1 | credential_id | A         |      186235 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credentials |          1 | ix_credentials_data  |            1 | data          | A         |      186235 |       20 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

**credential_pair Indexes:**

```
+------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name                                    | Seq_in_index | Column_name             | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| credential_pairs |          0 | PRIMARY                                     |            1 | hidden_id               | A         |       69224 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credential_pairs |          0 | PRIMARY                                     |            2 | credential_id           | A         |       69224 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credential_pairs |          1 | ix_credential_pairs_credential_id           |            1 | credential_id           | A         |       69224 |       36 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credential_pairs |          1 | ix_credential_pairs_primary_credential_id   |            1 | primary_credential_id   | A         |       69224 |       36 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| credential_pairs |          1 | ix_credential_pairs_secondary_credential_id |            1 | secondary_credential_id | A         |       69224 |       36 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+------------------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

---

**UPDATE NOTES:**

AFAICT: The DISTINCT was superfluous... nothing really needed it, so I dropped it. In an attempt to follow Fabrizio's advice to get a where on the credential_pairs lookup I then altered the statement to read as:

```
SELECT credential_id 
FROM credential_pairs cp
WHERE cp.primary_credential_id = (SELECT credential_id FROM credentials WHERE data = AES_ENCRYPT('value 1','enc_key')) AND
    cp.secondary_credential_id = (SELECT credential_id FROM credentials WHERE data = AES_ENCRYPT('value 2','enc_key'))
```

And.... nothing. The statement takes just as long and the explain looks pretty much the same. So, I added an index to the primary and secondary columns with:

```
ALTER TABLE credential_pairs ADD INDEX `idx_credential_pairs__primary_and_secondary`(`primary_credential_id`, `secondary_credential_id`);
```

And... nothing.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys       | key                                         | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | cp          | index | NULL                | idx_credential_pairs__primary_and_secondary | 514     | NULL | 69217 | Using where; Using index |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | credentials | ref   | ix_credentials_data | ix_credentials_data                         | 22      |      |     1 | Using where              |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | credentials | ref   | ix_credentials_data | ix_credentials_data                         | 22      |      |     1 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
```

It says it's using the index, but it still looks like it's table scanning. So, I added a joint key (as per a'r's comment below) with:

```
ALTER TABLE credential_pairs ADD KEY (primary_credential_id, secondary_credential_id);
```

And... same result as with the index (are these functionally the same?).

Comment: Try adding a composite key on credential_pairs, eg. `ALTER TABLE credential_pairs ADD KEY (primary_credential_id, secondary_credential_id);`

Comment: are you originally trying to find ALL PAIRS that match a given set of values ("some value 1" and "some value 2") ? cause this is what the query is doing. There is no way to make this query faster as it will always have to make a full table scan. It looks as a mistake in the design because usually you should have a user and know his credential_id. once he supplies the token values, you use this credential_id to find the pair that belongs to him (exactly 1 pair and one row scanned only) and then verify the primary and secondary credentials in that pair against the entered token values.

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT is what is generating the "Use temporary", you usually want to avoid those when possible

Plus you are scanning the whole `credential_pair` table as you do not have any conditions against it so no indexes are used and the whole table is returned before applying the WHERE

hope it makes sense

**EDIT/ADD**

Try by starting from a different table, if I understand correctly, you have Table A, a Table B and a Table AB and you are starting the select from AB, try to start it from A

I haven't tested this, but you could try:

```
SELECT cp.credential_id
FROM credentials AS c1
    LEFT JOIN credential_pairs AS cp ON (c1.credential_id = cp.primary_credential_id)
    LEFT JOIN credentials AS c2 ON (cp.secondary_credential_id = c2.credential_id)
WHERE
    c1.data = AES_ENCRYPT('Some Value 1', 'encryption key')
    AND c2.data = AES_ENCRYPT('Some Value 2', 'encryption key');
```

I have had luck in the past by moving select tables around

Comment: What you added actually might slow down your query.  I believe that adding a (SELECT) into the WHERE only causes the sub-query to be executed for each value

Comment: Can you post some of the column content please ?